# iOS, Keep track of uploading and downloading files in popped views

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, singleton

I am working on chat application over iOS, which has an uploading/downloading requirement like whatsApp upload/download, and I'm using [SOMessage](https://github.com/SocialObjects-Software/SOMessaging) Library.

But, If I want to upload an image and popped from the view, then the upload will be cancelled, and i managed the upload/download in a singleton class.

Now, the upload is performed, but I cannot keep track of the UI changes when I enter the view again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your singleton you can keep track of all progress of transfers and when the view is entered again you can open just check to see if there is a current transfer and then show it's progress.

I have a controller for one of our apps that handles all uploading and downloading and keeps track of progress per item until the queue is finished.  Then you can clear the queue upon completion or reference the queue as a historical list of files sent/ received